# PC doesn't boot PC-BSD from USB

Tags: usb, boot, freebsd, pc-bsd

I've got a problem with a friend's PC: I'm installing a FreeBSD server and to make easier the installation for my friend I'm using the PC-BSD DVD. Surprise! The CD reader doesn't read DVDs, so I'm using a USB stick to perform the install. The PC seems supporting USB boot because I can choose it in the boot sequence, but the PC-BSD installation doesn't start, booting the OS installed in the primary HD.

I have not physic access to the PC and I can't have at the moment more informations. What do you think about?

Thanks and sorry for my terrible English.

Tancredi Orlando.

Answer (score 1):

How did you get the install onto the USB-stick?

Use unetbootin
http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Format and install the latest FreeBSD they offer, and then extract your ISO, which you used to burn the install DVD, onto the thumb-drive's root.

that worked for me. let me know if you have other questions

Comment: Don't use unetbootin, they have a USB image specifically made... http://www.pcbsd.org/content/view/21/11/#USB

Comment: yea but when i tired to use that it didnt work, when taking the unetbootin path and then copying the contents from any of the install-ISOs to the root of the newly formatted USB-drive it works.

Comment: I used the DVD ISO to make the USB stick via unetbootin but didn't work...
The first time i made the USB stick using dd and the latest .img

Comment: did you use the ISO they suggested? because that is what you need to make it work. so you install the one from their dropdown like FreeBSD 8.0/8.0_64. after it is all done you close unetbootin and open your DVD iso, then extract all the files from the ISO onto the thumb drive.. then it should work